# Graph of $T$ closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

$T:D\subsetneq X\to Y$ be a linear map, $X,Y$ are normed linear spaces,Then $T$ is closed $\Leftrightarrow$

$1.$ $D$ is closed

$2. T(D)$ is closed

$3.T(D)$ is bounded

$4.$ graph of $T$ is closed.

The answer is $4$, but I need counter examples for others, could anyone provide me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D=\{0\}$. Then for any $T$, closed or not, 1, 2 and 3 hold.

Edit: I may have misunderstood the question. If the domain of $T$ is just $D$ and not $X$, then $T$ may be closed without $D$ being closed, for example, $X=Y=\mathbb R, T=\mathrm{id},D=(0,1)$.

Comment: If we are talking about linear maps then $D$ must be a vector subspace.